# 2 класс перенос слов

Tags: перенос

можно ли переносить слова ужи, заяц, осел, язык, Олег, ужин, пою, улей,урок

Comment: Я предлагаю на такие вопросы не отвечать!Тут ничего сложного нет, пусть дети сами справляются. А то вырастают и собственное имя не могут написать без ошибок!

Answer (score 2):

Из приведенного перечня можно разделить для переноса только слово "за-яц"

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы узнать правила переноса слов, я Вам порекомендую скачать вот это учебное пособие отсюда: http://www.alleng.ru/d/rusl/rusl541.htm. При помощи него Вы научитесь переносить слова.